# frmMain is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, winforms

OK this is what I have. I have my main form `frmMain.cs` and I have a `class.cs`. I was doing an RSSFeed for my email and I get the error:

> inaccessible due to its protective level.

On my `class.cs` I have the following code:

```
public class RSSFeed
{
    public void CheckForEmails()
    {
        string GmailAtomUrl = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom";
        XmlUrlResolver xmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
        xmlResolver.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Settings.Default.GmailUser, Settings.Default.GmailPassword);
        XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(GmailAtomUrl);
        xmlReader.XmlResolver = xmlResolver;
        try
        {
            XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://purl.org/atom/ns#");
            XDocument xmlFeed = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);

            var emailItems = from item in xmlFeed.Descendants(ns + "entry")
                select new
                {
                    Author = item.Element(ns + "author").Element(ns + "name").Value,
                    Title = item.Element(ns + "title").Value,
                    Link = item.Element(ns + "link").Attribute("href").Value,
                    Summary = item.Element(ns + "summary").Value
                };

            frmMain.MsgList.Clear();
            frmMain.MsgLink.Clear();
            foreach (var item in emailItems)
            {
                if (item.Title == String.Empty)
                {
                    frmMain.MsgList.Add("Message from " + item.Author + ", There is no subject and the summary reads, " + item.Summary);
                    frmMain.MsgLink.Add(item.Link);
                }
                else
                {
                    frmMain.MsgList.Add("Message from " + item.Author + ", The subject is " + item.Title + " and the summary reads, " + item.Summary);
                    frmMain.MsgLink.Add(item.Link);
                }
            }

            if (emailItems.Count() > 0)
            {
                if (emailItems.Count() == 1)
                {
                    frmMain.lblEmail.Text = ("You have one new email, would you like me to read it to you");
                }
                else 
                {
                    frmMain.lblEmail.Text("You have " + emailItems.Count() + "new emails");
                }
            }
            else if (frmMain.QEvent == "CheckForNewEmails" && emailItems.Count() == 0)
            { 
                frmMain.lblEmail.Text("You have no new emails"); frmMain.QEvent = String.Empty;
            }
        }
        catch 
        { 
            frmMain.lblEmail.Text("You have submitted invalid log in information"); 
        }
    }
}
```

And then I have on my main form a timer tick event:

```
public void tmrEmail_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblEmail.Text = ("New Emails " + RSSFeed.CheckForEmails);
}
```

What I am not understanding is when I have the label in my RSSFeed or on my main form timer tick. I get the error. I have changed everything to `public` and it still is throwing the error.

Am I missing something or do I not have everything I should have?

Also I am going to have another form that is just dedicated to email. Would it be better to do away with the RSSFeed.cs and just code the winform? The only thing this is doing is creating a label when I have new emails.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Also it works fine within a one form. Its just the label not working.

Comment: You're referring to `frmMain` as a class - when you should be using an *object* of that class.

Comment: this is what i have on the frmMain

Comment: public partial class frmMain : Form
    {
       
        public static List<string> MsgList = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> MsgLink = new List<string>();
        int EmailNum = 0;
        public static String QEvent;
        frmMain frm = new frmMain()

Comment: That `CheckForEmails` method is too tightly coupled to `frmMain` and should probably belong to it. If you rename a label, then the class `RSSFeed` will stop compiling, that's no good. Make each class do what that class does and do not mix responsibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `static` keyword from your class and method. Should be `public static class RSSFeed` and `public static void CheckForEmails()`

You need to pass an instance of the frmMain to the method too. E.g.:

```
public static void CheckForEmails(frmMain frmMainInstance)
```

Putting it all together:

```
public static class RSSFeed
{
    public static void CheckForEmails(frmMain frmMainInstance)
    {
        string GmailAtomUrl = "https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom";
        XmlUrlResolver xmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();

        // ... rest of your code ...
    }
}
```

And the call to it would be something like:

```
public void tmrEmail_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The following line will produce a compile error because
    // CheckForEmails doesn't return a value
    // lblEmail.Text = ("New Emails " + RSSFeed.CheckForEmails(this);
    // Try this instead:
    RSSFeed.CheckForEmails(this);
}
```

*Note that I am assuming `tmrEmail_Tick` is a method in `frmMain`, hence I am passing `this` as the argument to `CheckForEmails`*.

Instead of making `RSSFeed` and `CheckForEmails` static you could instantiate an instance of `RSSFeed`:

```
public void tmrEmail_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RSSFeed feed = new RSSFeed();
    feed.CheckForEmails(this);
}
```

Note that you still need to pass frmMain instance as an argument to `CheckForEmails`.

Comment: I never really did a RSS feed on a class.cs. I always did it in the form itself.  But I also will be doing about 10 different feeds.

Comment: Yes its the timer tick is in the frmMain. I am building a digital assistant program and I have done all of it before on a one form basis. Since I am on vacation for a month I am redoing the app and making it multiple forms

Comment: Ok I see what your doing and what I did wrong. I will give this a try and get back to you. Also it was originally frmMain.Ivan.SpeakAsync so if I do implement it back to the original it would be the same, correct?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by `frmMain.Ivan.SpeakAsync`?

Comment: I created a digital assistant like Jarvis off Iron Man. When I first done this program I used one form. But when I used System.Speech the synthesizer was named Ivan. So the Ivan.SpeakAsync is the speech part. I am redoing the program. Instead off the RSS feed in a private void on the main form. I want to do an Rss feed like the question. But I will have the label and the synthesizer. So the label will say "you have new emails" and at the same time the computer will vocalize the same message.

Comment: FrmMain.lblEmail.Text WA originally frmMain.Ivan.SpeakAsync. Just look at the code where the label is at.

Comment: I know it will work. I am just curious. Because I am taking a one form with over 8,000 lines of code and seperating them out to multiple forms. The thing is this is just basic a prototype per se. The finished product will have dictation as well

Comment: @Diamond GeezeR  it still does not work. All I want is the label to to tell me how many emails I have. for example,  "New Emails " + emailCount".. However i still have the same error for the labels in the RSSFeed. Even after I passed everything in the instance. Probably what i will do is forget the RSSFeed and do each one on a form by itself

Comment: The label is probably private to the form. Add a public method to the form to set the label's text, e.g. `public void SetLabelText(string text) { lblEmail.Text = text; }` and call that from RSSFeed, e.g. `frmMain.SetLabelText("You have no new emails.");`.

Comment: It might work but when I do the Weather, Finance, and others RSSFeeds there are labels as well if I do all of them    public void SetLabelText(string text) { lblEmail.Text = text; } and I call it frmMain.SetLabelText("...."); would this cause problems with the other labels formatted the same way, even though I am calling different feeds